# What is the difference between "I forgot" and "I almost forgot"

Tags: differences, phrase-usage

"I forgot" and "I almost forgot" appear to be interchangeable phrases meaning "I did not remember". But the fact that I hear the longer one used more commonly (especially in scripted television or literature) leads me to think that there is some special meaning conveyed; otherwise the simpler phrase would probably be used instead.

So what is the difference between "I forgot" and "I almost forgot"? Examples using the two phrases would be very much appreciated.

Comment: When you almost forget something you remember it at the last moment.  When you forget something you never remember it at all.

Comment: When you *Almost forget* something, you usually are saved from forgetting about it by something that happens to remind you of it.

Comment: @Jim I would dispute that when you *forget* something that you never remember it. Otherwise why would you ever use the word *forgot*. If you never remembered that you had forgotten something, you would not know that you had forgotten it, would you?

Comment: @WS2 well you never remember it when it matters.  If your mother asked you to take out the garbage and she comes home and sees that you haven’t and questions you about it you will claim, “I forgot”- that is, you never remembered to do it when you were supposed to. Now the truck has already come and gone and it’s too late.

Comment: @Jim But my guess is that when your mother mentioned it, you remembered that you had forgotten - unless that is you were losing your memory at a young age!

Comment: @WS2 exactly-  but remembering it at that point is too late.  there is a time window where the remembering must take place.  If you failed to remember within that time window then “you forgot”- Even if you remember it later.  If you remember it near the last possible moment within the time window then “you *almost* forgot”. I’m sure my mother would have been very displeased if I had responded, “No, I remembered” “When did you remember?” “Just now when you asked me about it.”

Comment: @Jim So critical to the difference between *forgot* and *almost forgot* is the length of the time window. Presumably this is something that differs according to circumstance. Can we say the time window ends at the point when it becomes too late, for all practical purposes, of making amends for having forgotten?